# Using RegEx to match all substring except those who start specific char

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following string:

string = '"General Slocum" 15 June 1904 East River _ human factor *%*_ %& 4'

**Q: Using RegEx, extract entire string except substrings who start with S.**

Code for finding substring that starts with S:

`print(re.findall('S[\w]+', string)`

output: ['Slocum']

The best solution I came up with, using the sub method:

`print(re.sub('S\w+', '',string))`

output: "General " 15 June 1904 East River. _ human factor *%*_ %& 4

=====================================================================

**Problem:** Not able to write a regex that recognize all substrings that starts with the specific char S, and then return all except for these substrings.

Example :

`print(re.findall('[^ S\w+][\w\%\d\&\.]+', string))`

output: ['"General', '%__', '%&']

Comment: What is your desired output? You want to ignore words that start with an `S`?

Answer (score 3):

Using re.findall you can use a capture group for what you want to keep, and match what you don't want to keep.

Depending on how specific you want the pattern to be, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)S\S*|(\S+)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `S\S*` Match an `S` char and optional non whitspace chars
- `|` Or
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kf8iuT/1)

Or for only word characters:

```
(?<!\S)S\w+|(\S+)
```

Here the `S\w+` matches an `S` char and 1 or more word chars, matching at least 2 chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/okWJvQ/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)S\S*|(\S+)"
string = '"General Slocum" 15 June 1904 East River _ human factor _%__ %& 4'
print ([s for s in re.findall(pattern, string) if s])
```

Output

```
['"General', '15', 'June', '1904', 'East', 'River', '_', 'human', 'factor', '_%__', '%&', '4']
```

Comment: Thank you.

I understand \S matches any non-space.
Still haven't figure out how ?<! sets the boundary. 
? - refers to one or more instances  meaning it will match any of the following <!\S

Comment: @nadav_n the `(?<!\S)` is a negative lookbehind to assert that what is directly to the left from the current position is not a non whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex approach that splits the input and then checks if each element doesn't start with letter `s`:

```sh
string = '"General Slocum" 15 June 1904 East River _ human factor _%__ %& 4'

print ([s for s in string.split() if not s.lower().startswith('s')])
```

**Output:**

```
['"General', '15', 'June', '1904', 'East', 'River', '_', 'human', 'factor', '_%__', '%&', '4']
```